# Title tag with regex

Tags: php, regex

How to put a h2 tag to a sentence?

```
$text = "paragraph 1
*some title*
paragraph 2";
```

This is what I tried. It works here http://www.regexr.com/3clm4 but it does not work if I put that in a real php page. Do you know why and how to solve it?

```
$text = preg_replace("/\*([\w\s]+)\*/","<h2>\1<\/h2>",$text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: Didn't you just ask something very similar? Use a standard solution like markdown and get a proven and tested library to convert it to html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were quite close to the working solution. The exact code to use is:

```
$t = preg_replace("/\*([\w\s]+)\*/","<h2>\\1</h2>",$text);
```

You need to use `"\\1"` because `"\1"` is actually a character representing the byte `0x01`.

Also, the `/` in the closing h2 tag needs not be escaped.

Comment: or use single quotes whenever you don't need to embed php variables.

Comment: Let me guess: the next question is: How can I avoid matching text inside `**....**` :)

Comment: why the / in the closing h2 tag do not need to be escaped?

Comment: @Nrc because the replacement string is not a regular expression, therefore the '/' character holds no specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in your's backreference - you must use double slash (`"<h2>\\1</h2>"`), or use dollar (`'<h2>$1</h2>'`).

You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php in **replacement** section.